# Is there a program that would generate Rust structures from a XML schema file?

Tags: xml, xsd, rust

I know some programs can generate Java, C# or C++ classes from XSD files, but I am looking for something that would generate Rust code.

An example would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that this exists. When it comes to serialization/deserialization in general the project which is furthest IMO is [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde), and there's a sibling project [serde-xml](https://github.com/serde-rs/xml). The status there is that XML deserialization only works when you come with the struct code up front

Comment: @hansaplast Perhaps this situation will improve with procedural macros..

Comment: about two years have passed now ... are there any updates?

Comment: I found some prototype at https://github.com/ProgVal/rust-xml-schema, so if somebody is interested in lending a hand…

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is [xmlschemer](https://github.com/estk/xmlschemer). Unfortunately it hasn't been maintained, and uses some nightly features which make it impossible to compile. I even tried installing an old version of the nightly compiler but that failed too due compile errors in `rustc-ap-rustc_lexer`.

There's also [xml-schema](https://github.com/media-io/xml-schema) which I haven't tried yet.